# On Click Display content based on button id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, ejs

I have a modal that is opened by a dynamically created button and I want to display a custom content based on the cid(attribute of the generated button) of the button.

I have the following EJS code :

```
<ul>
  <% company.forEach(function(comp) { %>
   <li><%= comp.companyName %> <button class="btn btn-primary manageCompany" data-cid=<%=comp._id%> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageCompany_pp">Manage</button> </li>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

This generates a few buttons based on json data passed from an node app to the EJS template, on click it opens the modal below:

```
  <div class="modal fade " id="manageCompany_pp" tabindex="-1" cid="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="manageCompany_pp">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="manageCompany_content">Manage Company</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class='manageCompanyAlert'></div>
                          Name: <%= company[cid].companyName %> //<-- get cid attr .. somehow
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is how I'm passing the needed id from the button to the modal :

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#manageCompany_pp').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
        var cid = button.data('cid'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
        console.log('here' + cid);
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.attr('cid', cid);
    });
});
```

My idea was to use ejs, retrieve the cid attribute from the div and then somehow insert it into a line like:
    compName : <%= company[cid].companyName %>
But that doesn't work, I'm looking for any method to achieve this, can use juqery and angularjs too if there's a way to do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can use jquery and angularjs too if there's a way to do what I need

Well you could do it with angular assuming all code have a common scope using ng-click

```
<li><%= comp.companyName %> <button ng-click="selectedId = <%=comp._id%>" class="btn btn-primary manageCompany" data-cid=<%=comp._id%> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manageCompany_pp">Manage</button> </li>
```

This way angular can update the modal on click

```
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class='manageCompanyAlert'></div>
            Name: {{ selectedId }}  <!-- get cid attr -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Close but I need to also use it within ejs code like Name: <%= company[{{selectedId}}].companyName %>

Comment: why man? You're mixing up way too many framework. Chose one and stick with it

Comment: I'm using ejs and angular, not that many and I do it because each simplifies different things.